# How can Spark read pipe delimited text file which doesnt have file extension

Tags: apache-spark

I have a pipe delimited text file which doesnt have a file extension. Checking file content

```
$ head -4 data/books/books
0|3-88623-803-7|GARDENING|2003-11-07|Editora FTD|174.99
1|5-72448-672-4|TECHNOLOGY-ENGINEERING|2012-08-08|Wolters Kluwer|140.99
2|7-64433-458-3|SOCIAL-SCIENCE|2015-11-14|Bungeishunju|7.99
3|1-18243-251-3|MATHEMATICS|1997-02-22|Hachette Livre|34.99
```

I tried to read file as spark dataframe, but I noticed the delimiter is not picked up:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[4]").appName("myApp").getOrCreate()

val data = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("inferSchema", "false").textFile("data/books/books")
data.show()
data.printSchema()


+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|0|3-88623-803-7|G...|
|1|5-72448-672-4|T...|
|2|7-64433-458-3|S...|
|3|1-18243-251-3|M...|

root
|-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.textFile` use `.csv`.

---

**`Using .csv:`**

```
spark.read.option("delimiter","|").option("header","false").csv("books").show()
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
//|_c0|          _c1|                 _c2|       _c3|           _c4|   _c5|
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
//|  0|3-88623-803-7|           GARDENING|2003-11-07|   Editora FTD|174.99|
//|  1|5-72448-672-4|TECHNOLOGY-ENGINE...|2012-08-08|Wolters Kluwer|140.99|
//|  2|7-64433-458-3|      SOCIAL-SCIENCE|2015-11-14|  Bungeishunju|  7.99|
//|  3|1-18243-251-3|         MATHEMATICS|1997-02-22|Hachette Livre| 34.99|
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
```

**`Using .textFile:`**

Results `RDD[String]` then by using **.split** and **.map** we need to convert `RDD to dataframe`.

```
spark.read.textFile("books").map(x => x.split("\\|")).
map(x =>(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5))).
toDF().
show()
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
//| _1|           _2|                  _3|        _4|            _5|    _6|
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
//|  0|3-88623-803-7|           GARDENING|2003-11-07|   Editora FTD|174.99|
//|  1|5-72448-672-4|TECHNOLOGY-ENGINE...|2012-08-08|Wolters Kluwer|140.99|
//|  2|7-64433-458-3|      SOCIAL-SCIENCE|2015-11-14|  Bungeishunju|  7.99|
//|  3|1-18243-251-3|         MATHEMATICS|1997-02-22|Hachette Livre| 34.99|
//+---+-------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+------+
```